# D3.js v6 path not aligning inside line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two line charts. One I coded [here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/NWpJajW?editors=1010) and the other [here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/rNmVdBr?editors=0010) that I copy pasted to compare why mine did not align correctly. Neither chart is using a transform to translate the line. What am I missing in the chart that does align correctly. Thank you.

Not working correctly chart:

```
var svg = d3.select("body") //create Svg element
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height",500)
   .attr("width", 700)
   .style("border", "solid 1px red")
   .attr("transform","translate(100,0)"); // To align svg at the center in the output tab.
var data = [
    { day:0, stock_value: 0 },
    { day:5, stock_value: 100 },
    { day:10, stock_value: 200 },
    { day:15, stock_value: 400 },
    { day:20, stock_value:150 }];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.day))
              .range([0,500]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.stock_value))
              .range([400,0]);

svg.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .attr('transform','translate(70,450)');

svg.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
  .attr('transform','translate(70,50)');

svg.append('text')
  .text('days')
  .attr('transform','translate(270,490)');

svg.append('text')
  .text('value')
  .attr('transform','translate(30,300) rotate(-90)')

var generator = d3.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.day); })
                  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.stock_value); });

svg.append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .attr('d', generator)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','blue')
  .attr('stroke-width','2px');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track!

Looks like we need to apply the same transform to our path as we're applying to our axes here.

You can see in the screenshots that both the x-axis and y-axis are being offset in the svg using a transform -- that's so that the y-axis can be seen inside of the space created for the svg, inside the red line. If we *don't* apply that transform, then we won't be able see our y-axis.

So in order for our path to line up with our axes, we need to apply that same transformation to our path. :)

[Updated pen.](https://codepen.io/theemattoliver/pen/YzVXmVr?editors=0010)

By the way, in D3, one thing you will encounter a lot is the so-called "margin convention." It's completely up to you of course and there are definitely arguments to be made for not using it, but if it's helpful, [the creator of D3 wrote up a demo of the margin convention that I think illustrates it pretty well which is linked here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/margin-convention).

I hope this helps! ✌️

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 80},
     width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body") //create Svg element
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height",500)
   .attr("width", 700)
   .style("border", "solid 1px red")
   .attr("transform","translate(100,0)"); // To align svg at the center in the output tab.

var data = [
    { day:0, stock_value: 0 },
    { day:5, stock_value: 100 },
    { day:10, stock_value: 200 },
    { day:15, stock_value: 400 },
    { day:20, stock_value:150 }];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.day))
              .range([0,500]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.stock_value))
              .range([400,0]);

svg.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .attr('transform',`translate(${70}, ${450})`);

svg.append('g')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
  .attr('transform',`translate(${70},${50})`);

svg.append('text')
  .text('days')
  .attr('transform','translate(270,490)');

svg.append('text')
  .text('value')
  .attr('transform','translate(30,300) rotate(-90)')

var generator = d3.line()
                  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.day); })
                  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.stock_value); });

svg.append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .attr('d', generator)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('stroke','blue')
  .attr('stroke-width','2px')

// both of your axes are having a transform applied to account for your svg's margins, so apply the same values to your path here:

  .attr('transform',`translate(${70},${50})`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[image: d3 axis transform]
[image: d3 axis transform]